# When to set the initial value of the form?

Tags: react-query

I have these codes, if the user opens the form dialog for the first time, it works well.

```js
function PostFormDialog({ id }) {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const post = useQuery(['post', id], () => fetchPost(id))
  const update = useMutation(() => updatePost(formValue), {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(['post', id])
    },
  })
  if (post.isLoading) {
    return 'loading...'
  }
  return (
    <Dialog {...dialogProps}>
      <Form initialValue={post} onSubmit={update.mutate} />
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

But when I submit the form once, I quickly open the dialog box again, and it will display the last data. The data is being retrieved at this time, but isLoading is false.

I want:

- After opening the form dialog box, if the data is out of date, wait for the data to be loaded and display `loading...`
- If you are editing the form, switching tabs may cause data to be retrieved, but `loading...` is not displayed at this time

This is hard for me. I can avoid it by using optimistic updates, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After opening the form dialog box, if the data is out of date, wait for the data to be loaded and display loading...

if your `PostFormDialog` unmounts after it is closed, you can set `cacheTime` for your query to a "smaller time". It defaults to 5 minutes so that data can be re-used. If you set `cacheTime: 0`, the cached data will be removed immediately when you unmount the component (= when you close the dialog).

Every new open of the dialog will result in a hard loading state.

> If you are editing the form, switching tabs may cause data to be retrieved, but loading... is not displayed at this time

`loading...` is not displayed because the query is no longer in `loading` state. The extra `isFetching` boolean will be true though, which can be used for background updates.

However, when populating forms with "initial data", background updates don't much sense, do they? What if the user has changed data already?

You can:

- turn off background refetches with `staleTime: Infinity` to just load initial data once.
- Keep the background refetches, and then maybe display a "data has changed" notification to the user?
- Do not initialize the form with initialValue, but keep it `undefined` and fall back to the server value during rendering. I've written about this approach [here](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/practical-react-query#keep-server-and-client-state-separate)

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with react query options. For example:

```
useQuery(
  ["post", id],
  () => fetchPost(id),
  { refetchOnMount: true }
);
```

Comment: This also has the same problem, because `isLoading` is `false`, so when the dialog is opened, the value of `initialValue` is stale post data